# change gridview cell color on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have given the condition in rowdatabound however it give me "" value in lblstatus.....  i want to change background color of cell as per given condition below mentioned is code and design my values in grid are populated in item template and label within item template

```
   protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
      {           
        String lblstatus = "";
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            foreach (GridViewRow row in grv_taskfilter.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < grv_taskfilter.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    //String header = GridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                    lblstatus = row.Cells[i].Text.ToString();

                    if (lblstatus == "Not yet started")
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                    }

                    if (lblstatus == "In progress")
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                    }

                    if (lblstatus == "Alert")
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                    }
                    if (lblstatus == "Missed deadline")
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    }
                    if (lblstatus == "Not Applicable")
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you step through and it got into the foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
      {           
        String lblstatus = "";
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
```

**this foreach is not requried  you are in row data bound event means every time new row bound goes here**

```
 //  foreach (GridViewRow row in grv_taskfilter.Rows)
           // {
                for (int i = 0; i <e.row.cells.Count; i++)
                {

                    lblstatus = e.row.Cells[i].Text.ToString();//use e.rows.cell[]

                    if (lblstatus == "Not yet started")
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                    }

                    if (lblstatus == "In progress")
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                    }

                    if (lblstatus == "Alert")
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                    }
                    if (lblstatus == "Missed deadline")
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    }
                    if (lblstatus == "Not Applicable")
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet;
                    }
            //    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: i have a label in each cell of gridview i need to find the text of label and then change the color as per condition i have such 18 column and many rows so how do i change each cell background